# Different login scheme of user and admin in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two log in page one for user and another for admin and both uses different table
how authenticate from admin using Auth component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Routing Prefix by enabling/defining it in core.php

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'user'));
```

You can use n numbers of routing prefixes.

Then use following syntax:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Manage posts',
    array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login')
);
```

Comment: Btw why are you creating two login pages, if only one can serve the purpose.